# how to find the sqlserver name(data source) used by sharepoint?

Tags: c#, sharepoint

Can u people Help me How to get the sqlserver name used by sharepoint programatically??
 is there any such api provided like i have installed sharepoint on the sqlnamed instance.
How to get the sqlservername.

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code should help you and you need to run this code from the SharePoint Server or WFE server.

```
        public String GetSharePointSQLServerName()
    {
        String sServerName = "notFound";
        foreach (var item in SPFarm.Local.Servers)
        {
            foreach (var svc in item.ServiceInstances)
            {
                 if (svc is SPDatabaseServiceInstance)
                {
                    SPDatabaseServiceInstance s = svc as SPDatabaseServiceInstance;                        
                    sServerName = item.DisplayName+"\\"+s.Instance;
                }
            }             
        }
        return sServerName;
    }
```

Comment: Here I am getting the server name as "Demo-64-Test".But i have installed sqlserver as Named instance. "Demo-64-Test\SQLNamed".I have to get this one.

Comment: @Kusek:Thnks It Helps me.But i have a Doubt.If i Installed The sqlserver as Default one then it gives the Default instance only??is is possible with above code??

Comment: HI it is not getting the instance name in server farm???
is thee is other way to do this ??/

Comment: @Cute: I have updated the Answer already to get the Instance of the DB Server.

Comment: the same i have used but i am not getting it says the role as invalid for the machine whre my named sqlserver insatnce is installed in server farm

Comment: @Cute: I came across here by your question. I am also facing same issue. probably you could solved this issue. I have added my question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244370/sharepoint-2010-topology-with-this-issue here. so can you please guide me. I am using sharepoint 2010.

Answer (score 0):

So what is if you do not have a named database instance?

better you use this:

```
var serverNames = from server in SPFarm.Local.Servers
                  from service in server.ServiceInstances
                  where service is SPDatabaseServiceInstance
                  let dbInstance = (SPDatabaseServiceInstance) service
                  select dbInstance.NormalizedDataSource;
```

If you have multiple names for your sql server (like aliases) the returned collection will have multiple entries. Just take the first of the collection.